# Php array splice

Tags: php

I am new to php and was wondering if anybody could help me with splitting an array of sentences.

I want to divide the array into two parts, and then divide the first part again into 10 parts, and echo the results.

If I had 100 sentences it would look like this:

```
echo $Part1-1;  // 5 Sentences
echo $Part1-2;  // 5 Sentences
echo $Part1-3;  // 5 Sentences
echo $Part1-4;  // 5 Sentences
echo $Part1-5;  // 5 Sentences
echo $Part1-6;  // 5 Sentences
echo $Part1-7;  // 5 Sentences
echo $Part1-8;  // 5 Sentences
echo $Part1-9;  // 5 Sentences
echo $Part1-10; // 5 Sentences

echo $Part2; // 50 Sentences
```

If there are not enough sentences then Part1, X to 10 should be blank.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your array of sentences? Different languages and different writing style could mean different ways to split into sentences :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$outerParts = array_chunk($sentences, 50);
$innerParts1 = array_chunk($outerParts[0], 5);
```